# ASP.NET Unmanaged Memory Leaking

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, iis-express

At my company we are developing an ASP.NET web-application. The application itself utilizes a large number of number input elements at the frontend (~ 8k) which are in a table. Using these input fields the user can edit data in a spreadsheet-like manner. The code for generating the spreadsheet is essentially a nested for-loop.

The problem we are experiencing is that the application has ~12MB of memory usage when deployed. After the first page request the usage increases to over 100MB and stays there. Each follow-up request increases the memory usage until it reaches 700-1000MB. At that point the application will run GC cycles every 150-200ms, but only a few MB will be freed each time. If a user spams the refresh button they can get the site to crash with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

[image: Visual Studio Diagnostics]

The origin of the error is in the table generation code of our Razor template. When analyzing the memory usage with dotMemory it turned out that most of the memory is unmananged. The strange thing is that the heap is only 6 MB large. We are pretty clueless as to what is causing this. The code for generating an input element is simply `@Html.EditorFor(model => ...)`. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
[image: dotMemory Snapshot]
[image: dotMemory #2]

Comment: 8k input fields in a single page? Seems like you should redesign the UI and how the data is entered. I doubt even the user want's to see/edit 8000 input fields at the same time.

Comment: @Esko I agree, my team does not value the frontend as much, so it was designed somewhat poorly. ATM the 8k fields are there to stay, although I am planning on mentioning the issue in the next stand-up. Another thing is that I am a new developer and nobody seems to have cared in the past so I am unsure as to how I should approach the issue.

Comment: I understand the problem you are facing. Maybe you can use these memory problems as an example of the problems caused by the poor UI-design. Accompany this with and example of how you would redesign the UI to be more efficient and user friendly. Maybe let the user select a date range to edit (if the application uses dates) and then just show textboxes needed for those dates? Good luck :)

Comment: Clearly UI is bad, and razor might have a problem generation that much html for each user ... better to handle Front-end in JS frameworks and leave to the server back-end tasks ...

Comment: @Esko Ok, I will do as you suggest. I will probably utilize lazy-loading and only display text fields when a field is being edited and a label if it isn't. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've had this kind of problem before,I just did as Vladimir said JS for the frontend , AJAX to send the data (sending only edited fields) and the backend is a json result action returns errors or success to the view. again the js will handle things on the view side.